# Fitting log returns of 38 stocks with a multivariate skew t-distribution, R, error in printing out parameters

Tags: r, simulation, data-fitting

I am trying to fit the data of 38 stocks (6 months log returns ) with a multivariate skew t distribution, using :
fit = mstFit(DATAR, fixed.nu = NULL, trace = FALSE, title = NULL, description = NULL)
the problem is that when I try to print parameters, Omega, Alpha, Beta say, with the $ operator: fit$Omega, I get this message: 
$ operator not defined for this S4 class

I red other topics about this but I could not find a solution that could really help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at `str(fit)` and it'll show you the structure of the object that is returned. From this – and assuming you're using the `fMultivar` package, since you don't specify –  it looks like you want `fit@fit$dp$Omega`, etc. In the future, providing a reproducible example will help people help you...

Comment: Thank you so much man, it is working now. I am sorry if I was not that precise or I did not provide a reproducible example, this was my first post, but I appreciate it, I will consider your suggestion